# Bootstrap 4 nav bar first nav item not highlighted and scrollspy issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am running into a problem and I’m not sure to resolve it. I have a bootstrap 4 navbar with scrollspy enabled so that the nav bar updates when you scroll through the different sections of the page.

I also have a jquery function that does smooth scrolling so that the page does not immediately jump when you click on a navigation link. I have two problems

My website: https://codepen.io/tidus198/pen/deWpvX 3

1. Problem is the nav bar scrollspy. The page by default does not make my first nav item active. The **About** nav item is not highlighted when you first visit the page or if you scroll all the way to the top of the page. If you scroll down a little bit, the **About** link becomes active in the nav bar. This is occurring because I made my navbar fixed so it scrolls along with the page. How do I get it to work so that the first nav item is active by default?
2. If you click on one of the nav items, it scrolls past the title of the section (i.e. shows content instead of heading). I fixed this by using the jquery offset function (getting the top value and subtracting it by a set amount) to display the actual heading instead of the content right away. So now, when you click on for example **Contact**, it actually scrolls to the Contact text. But the issue is if you click on Contact, the navbar displays Portfolio as the active item. How would I go about fixing this? 
   The offset works but broke the navigation item.

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>My Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" type="text/css" />    
    </head>

    <body id = "body">
    <header id="test">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" >
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="navpic" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" ></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-pills ml-auto" id="homenav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#test">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>


          <section class="container">

            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                  <img id="mypic" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                  <h1 class="display-5">Your Name Here</h1>
                  <p class="lead">Front-End Developer and UX/UI designer, with practical experience in project management, branding strategy, and
                    creative direction; devoted to functional programming and information architecture.</p>
                  <hr class="my-4">
                  <p class="small">Web Developer - User Experience Designer - Graphic Artist</p>

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>
          </section>
        </header>

        <main>
          <section id="content-container" class="container">
            <div class="row" id="portfolio">
              <div class="col-12">
                <h2 class="display-5 text-center text-white text-uppercase mb-3">Portfolio</h2>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">
                <div class="card w-100">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    Image One
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">
                <div class="card w-100">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">

                  <div class="card-footer text-center">Image Two</div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">
                <div class="card w-100">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    Image Three
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">
                <div class="card w-100">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">

                  <div class="card-footer text-center">Image Four</div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">
                <div class="card w-100">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    Image Five
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">
                <div class="card w-100">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">

                  <div class="card-footer text-center">Image Six</div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

          </section>
        </main>

        <footer>
          <section class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron mt-2">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <h2 class="display-4 text-center pb-2" id="contact">Contact Me</h2>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="emailaddr">Email</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailaddr" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="123-456-7890">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="textarea">Message</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </form>

                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                  <p class="lead">Feel free to contact me if you have any additional questions on my portfolio. You can either email me directly
                    at
                    <a href="mailto:myemail@myemail.com?subject=Porfolio Question">
                      myemail@myemail.com</a> or fill out the contact form.
                  </p>

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

          </section>
        </footer>

      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
blockquote {
  border-left: none;
}

#body {
    background-color: #464646;
    padding-top: 65px; 
    position: relative;
}

#mypic {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#navpic {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

}

.jumbotron #contact {
  margin-top: -50px;
}

form label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#homenav > li > a:hover{
    background-color:grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  } 

#about{
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('body').scrollspy({ target: '.navbar' });

    $('.nav-link').on('click', function(){
        var clickedItem = $(this).attr('href');
       $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(clickedItem).offset().top - 80
       }, 1500);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some minor tweaking and it's looking right to me. See my fork here: https://codepen.io/mdlanglais/pen/OZmWNV

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Portfolio</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" type="text/css" />    
</head>

<body id = "body" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbarNav">
<header id="test">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" >
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="navpic" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" ></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-pills ml-auto" id="homenav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#test">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


      <section class="container">

        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
              <img id="mypic" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
              <h1 class="display-5">Your Name Here</h1>
              <p class="lead">Front-End Developer and UX/UI designer, with practical experience in project management, branding strategy, and
                creative direction; devoted to functional programming and information architecture.</p>
              <hr class="my-4">
              <p class="small">Web Developer - User Experience Designer - Graphic Artist</p>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </section>
    </header>

    <main>
      <section id="content-container" class="container">
        <div class="row" id="portfolio">
          <div class="col-12">
            <h2 class="display-5 text-center text-white text-uppercase mb-3">Portfolio</h2>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">
            <div class="card w-100">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-footer text-center">
                Image One
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">
            <div class="card w-100">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">

              <div class="card-footer text-center">Image Two</div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">
            <div class="card w-100">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-footer text-center">
                Image Three
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">
            <div class="card w-100">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">

              <div class="card-footer text-center">Image Four</div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">
            <div class="card w-100">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-footer text-center">
                Image Five
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-4">
            <div class="card w-100">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">

              <div class="card-footer text-center">Image Six</div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </section>
    </main>

    <footer>
      <section class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron mt-2">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <h2 class="display-4 text-center pb-2" id="contact">Contact Me</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="emailaddr">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailaddr" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="123-456-7890">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="textarea">Message</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
              </form>

            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
              <p class="lead">Feel free to contact me if you have any additional questions on my portfolio. You can either email me directly
                at
                <a href="mailto:myemail@myemail.com?subject=Porfolio Question">
                  myemail@myemail.com</a> or fill out the contact form.
              </p>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </section>
    </footer>

  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
blockquote {
  border-left: none;
}

#body {
    background-color: #464646;
    padding-top: 0px; 
    position: relative;
}

#mypic {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#navpic {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

}

.jumbotron #contact {
  margin-top: -50px;
}

form label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#homenav > li > a:hover{
    background-color:grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

#test {
  padding-top: 95px;
}

#about{
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('body').scrollspy({ target: '.navbar' });

  $('.nav-link').on('click', function(){
    var clickedItem = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(clickedItem).offset().top
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

Basically I set the About link as `.active` to begin with, removed the -80 from `.top` in the js, removed the `padding-top` from the `body` element and added some `padding-top` to the `#test` element in the css. It could probably be done with variations of the same idea.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize it was the body padding that was causing that issue with the nav bar first link. Removing the body padding actually resolved the first issue. As for the removing -80 from top, that does resolve it but the link shows the content rather than the title of the section I'm scrolling to. I guess there is no easy way to resolve that. What purpose does the .active class solve? I see the nav bar working either way even if it does not exist.

Comment: So it is! My thought process first was, lock down the issue where About wasn't active on page load so I forced it with `.active.` After adjusting the padding on `body` and the `#test` element it must not have been necessary. It doesn't serve any purpose at this point. If the scrollspy functionality were going to continue to misbehave, I'd probably next try to, upon `$('.nav-link').on('click', function()` etc., clear the color from all buttons and add the active class to the button that was just clicked.

Comment: If I'm understanding that the button clicked should immediately be the active link and not only once the scroll animation reaches the anchored element.

Comment: Got it. I think that might be built into the scrollspy function but no idea. I'll try using the console to log out the classes of the click item and see if that is the case. Thanks for all the help